# Problems Using Templates in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I am from Java backgroung and new to C++.
There is a template which i have made.

```
template <class T>
class Shape {
int val,val_new;

public:

Shape(T initval)
{
val=initval;
}

T get()
{
return val;
}

void set (T newval)
{
val_new = newval;
}
void copy()
{
this.val= val_new;
}
};
```

There is a class Rectangle to use this template

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle
{
private:
Shape<TwoPoint> val;
TwoPoint newval;
public:
Rectangle(TwoPoint i)
{
     val = new Shape<TwoPoint> (i);
}
Shape<TwoPoint> read()
{
     return val;
}

void load(TwoPoint newval)
{
     load_called=1;
     this.newval=newval;
}
void increment()
{
   val=val+1;
}

void decrement()
{
   val= val-1;
}
void actions()
{ 
 if (load_called)
value.set(new TwoPoint(newval));
}
};
```

TwoPoint is a class used for generics.

```
class TwoPoint
{
  int width;
  int value;
  public:
  TwoPoint(int v, int w)
  {
   value=v;
   width=w;
   }
   TwoPoint(TwoPoint t)
   {
    value= t.value;
    width= t.width;
   }
   int getWidth()
   {
     return width;
   }
    int getValue()
    {
       return value;
    }};
```

But i am getting a lot of errors like constructor mismatches, conversion failures. Can somebody please help me.

There are errors like

```
 In constructor `Rectangle::Rectangle<TwoPoint>':
 error: no matching function for call to Shape<TwoPoint>:: Shape()'
 note: candidates are: Shape<T>::Shape<T> with [T = TwoPoint]
```

Two similar errors are there

Comment: It would be more useful if you provide us with a single translation unit that you fed to a compiler, and the error message(s) that it produced.

Comment: i am sorry. will surely do that next time i post a question.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First; in the following piece of code, `this` is indexed with '.', but `this` is a pointer so you should use `val = val_new;` (implicitly `this->val = val_new;`):

```
void copy() {
  this.val = val_new;
}
```

... should be...

```
void copy() {
  val = val_new;
  // or this->val = val_new;
}
```

Same problem at `Rectangle::load`.

Secondly: like others are saying, you should use `T val, val_new` instead of `int val, val_new`.

**And last but not least:**

```
Rectangle(TwoPoint i) {
     val = new Shape<TwoPoint> (i);
}
```

`val` should be initalized like this:

```
Rectangle(TwoPoint i)
    : val(Shape<TwoPoint> (i)) { }
```

There are two reasons for this:

1. If `val` is not initalized like this, the default constructor (`Shape<T>::Shape()`) is used, which does not exist.
2. The `new` keyword allocates new memory in C++ and returns a pointer. It should be left away since `val` is not a pointer but a value.

At constructors you can intialize member values by calling their constructors, or calling them with their value (auto-generated copy constructor). This should be prefixed with a colon an followed by the function body.

Comment: `void Rectangle:: load(TwoPoint)` 
insufficient contextual information to determine type

Answer (score 4):

There's a problem in your template declaration:

```
template <class T>
class Shape {
   int val,val_new;
public:
   Shape(T initval)
   {
      val=initval;
   }
   //....
};
```

The parameter `initval` has type `T`, but you're assigning it to an `int`. Perhaps you wanted your members also of type `T`?

```
template <class T>
class Shape {
   T val,val_new;
public:
   //....
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just as an example, near the begining of your shape class we see

```
int val,val_new;
Shape(T initval) {
    val = initval;
```

This code assumes that the type `T` is assignable to `int`. Since `TwoPoint` is not a numeric type, nor does it contain a conversion operator to `int`, there's no way you can instantiate `Shape<TwoPoint>`, as the template would not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Your error about the Shape() constructor is caused because you didn't use constructor initialization. In Rectangle, val gets default constructed before you ever get around to assigning it. And you didn't define a Shape() constructor.

Try:

```
Rectangle(TwoPoint i) :
    val(i)
{
}
```